# How long does it take for apple trees to regrow in Breath of the Wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In the Applean Forest, [there is a Korok seed](http://ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Central_Hyrule_Korok_Seed_58) which involves picking apples from a group of 3 identical-looking apple trees.

This poses an issue, as I *may* have *accidentally* chopped down those apple trees while gathering firewood...

[image: Forest with several trees missing]

How long will it take for the apple trees to regrow so I can collect my Korok Seed?

Comment: I know a majority of things respawn after a Blood Moon. Perhaps see if they are there after the next one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though the Trees will come back pretty quickly if you leave and re-enter the area, according to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/61jiws/does_anyone_know_how_to_grow_back_apples_on_trees/) you may need to wait a bit for the fruit to come back.

> ...I've tried everyone's suggestions and it didn't work but I finally found out how this apple respawn work apparently **one apple will spawn every hour** this is not the game hour this is the **real world hour**...

So though it seems kind of counter-intuitive, Blood Moons **will not** respawn fruits, only waiting in game will. It should also be noted that you do need to wait the full real-time hour in game, changing your system clock will not trick the game into respawning fruit.

So my recommendation is just drop a map marker on the trees and go do other things for a bit. When you come back the trees should have their fruit again.

Comment: Good information, but I don't know if it fully addresses the timeline of respawn given the OPs issue. Is it one apple per hour for all trees, or one apple per hour per tree?

Comment: @Wondercricket One Apple per hour per tree, from what I have been able to find. It should be noted that this is one real time hour in game, you can not skip days at campfire/inn to make it grow faster nor change your system clock.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro bloodmoon does not re-spawn apples according to Reddit OPs testing, will add that to answer as well as I was expecting that bloodmoon would re-spawn fruit.

Comment: This is incorrect. There is no fixed respawn time because the process is entirely random.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty quickly.

I was chopping wood in the forest in front of Hateno Village and got distracted fighting some bokoblins. By the time I had killed them I'd moved a little way down the road away from the village and when I came back to the forest all (or most anyway) of the trees had regrown.

I would guess the trees basically regrow as soon as you are out of sight.

Comment: I came back after an hour and the trees had regrown. Unfortunately, the apples have yet to grow back.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Ah, the apples probably regrow differently as they're an ingredient..